# Python toolbox optional parameter use with if statement not functioning

Tags: python-3.x, arcpy

I am developing a Python Toolbox in ArcGIS Pro. One of the parameters allows the user to select a coordinate system from the built in ESRI coordinate systems. This part works fine. But when I incorporate "if" statement is "True" then the arcpy project syntax, it looks like the tool ran fine (no errors) but the output is not reprojected. (In the code this is param2).

I have verified the syntax with Arc Pro documentation and other SO posts. I've run debug in VS Code, I have also manually tested manually reprojected some of the feature classes which also work. I have also tried both "parameters[2].value" and "parameters[2].valueAsText".

Have also tried "if input in coord", if coord:, etc.
To clarify the user selects a built in ESRI projection which is optional. The data does not reproject nor does it error. My guess is I am not passing in the parameter2 correctly.

Why would this not reproject the data?

```
class Extract(object):
def __init__(self):
    """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
    self.label = "Extract"
    self.description = "The data extract tool will clip all datasets to the visual extent of the main map."
    self.canRunInBackground = False

def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
    name= "Parameter0",
    datatype = "GPString",
    displayName= "Geodatabase name",
    parameterType= "Required",
    direction= "Input")
    
    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
    name= "Parameter1",
    displayName= "Output Geodatabase Location",
    datatype = "DEFolder",
    parameterType= "Required",
    direction= "Input")

    param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
    name="GPSpatialReference",
    displayName="Projected Coordinate System",
    datatype="GPCoordinateSystem",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input")

    params = [param0, param1, param2]

    return params

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    val = parameters[0].valueAsText
    if val:
        if ".gdb" not in val:
            textdata = os.path.splitext(val)
            parameters[0].value = textdata[0] + ".gdb"

    return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
     #********CREATE GEODATABASES IN USERS CURRENT LOCATION********
    gdb_loc = os.path.join(parameters[1].valueAsText, parameters[0].valueAsText)

    #********DATA AND PATHS********
    aprxMap = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
    aoi = os.path.join(gdb_loc, 'AOI')

    #********PROJECTION DEFINITION AND VERIFICATION ********
    m = aprxMap.listMaps()[0]
    mv = m.defaultView

    extView = mv.camera.getExtent()
    print(extView)

    # Create a polygon geometry
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([extView.lowerLeft,
                                            extView.lowerRight,
                                            extView.upperRight,
                                            extView.upperLeft,
                                            extView.lowerLeft]))
    arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(polygon, aoi)

    for map in aprxMap.listMaps():
        coord = parameters[2].value
        for lyrs in map.listLayers():

            if parameters[2].value == True:
                arcpy.management.Project(lyrs, coord)
                messages.addMessage('Projecting....' + lyrs)

            if lyrs == 'AOI':
                pass
            try:
                arcpy.analysis.Clip(lyrs, aoi, os.path.join(str(gdb_loc) + '\\' + str(lyrs)))

                count = arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrs)
                messages.addMessage('{} has {} records'.format(lyrs, count[0]))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                continue
    return
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well, what *is* the value of `coord`, then? By its name it doesn't sound like it would be the same as `True`. Any chance you were trying to check it for truthiness? That's not done with `==`.

Comment: @Dan Getz I added a screenshot for clarity. The value of 'coord' is which ever ESRI built in coordinate system the user chooses. If they leave it blank the data is not reprojected (left in NAD83) if they choose a coordinate system. then that is what it is used.

Comment: OK, so it's not `True`, so don't compare it to `True`. Sounds like it's a string?

Comment: You got me thinking at I also tried if not coord is None:  (didn't work) In my description above I've also tried  "parameters[2].value" and "parameters[2].valueAsText" - neither worked. (I know you can bring in coordinates via wkt IDs but not sure if Toolbox needs it 'AsText' or not)..... any other thoughts? I've spent an entire day on this :( :(

Comment: Elsewhere in your code you have `if val:`, which would fail if it's an empty string, or `None`, or `False`, or even `0`.  You probably should try that with your coords value. You can also use `print(repr(coords))` to see what exactly it is.

Comment: @Dan Getz Thanks, tried that too...problem seems to be passing IN the user input parameter. Appreciate your response, guess I'll try Git Hub for help - no one else on SO offered suggestions :(

Comment: What is `if input in coord` supposed to do? Now I'm confused...`input` is a Python function that you'd have no reason to be using in ArcPy. Try `if coord:`, does that work? I explained earlier why it might.

Comment: @user2856 Hi. I saw that you answered this post 
  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416545/accessing-built-in-coordinate-systems-from-arcgis-pro-python-toolbox-tool  so I thought I would try to contact. I've been working for a week to pass my user selected projection system into my arcpro toolbox. (Confident that is the problem after tons of testing....)  Can you answer my post, as to what I am doing wrong?